# Why does an angularjs dependency array include the function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

To inject dependencies, we do the following:

```
inject(["$scope", "$compile", function ($scope, $compile) {
  ...
}]);
```

This syntax is weird! Putting the function inside the array seems really counter-intuitive to me. Is there a good reason why it was chosen like this? Why not

```
inject(["$scope", "$compile"], function ($scope, $compile) {
```

<strike>My preferred syntax would be:</strike>

```
inject("$scope", "$compile", function ($scope, $compile) {
```

but I understand that there would be a few [performance issues](http://jsperf.com/arguments/10) there. *(Removed because it seems to be confusing the question.)*

Comment: No I didn't. Why not the second option?

Comment: ^ (in response to a now deleted comment saying I answered my own question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, you'd want to assign a controller function to a variable, like with  `ngRoute` (which was part of core Angular early on), instead of registering it  with `.controller`:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/Book/:bookId', {
     templateUrl: 'book.html',
     controller: function($scope){
     }
  });
```

It helps to re-use the same variable for annotation as well.

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/Book/:bookId', {
     templateUrl: 'book.html',
     controller: ["$scope", function($scope){
     }]
  });
```

Yes, it's a bit counter-intuitive, but not completely out of the ballpark of reason.

Comment: Makes sense. Or in directives which specify their own controller.

Answer (score -1):

Not only performance:) It's because of the minify things. U can read about:
[Angular Inject minify](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05)

Comment: But the second option wouldn't interfere with minification.

Comment: But the third one interfere :) And not the best option to use anonim functions. Good style guid:
https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide